# GGPlot With Specifications

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
data=data.frame("grade"=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
                "class"=c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                "size"=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1),
                "var"=c('q33', 'q35', 'q39', 'q33', 'q35', 'q39'),
                "score"=c(5, 8, 7, 3, 7, 5))
```

My data have many group variables. 
First I want to just plot 'score' by 'grade' with a line

```
library(reshape2, ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = grade, y = score)) + geom_line()
```

It gives a funny graph because I have 'grade' repeated for  different classes and sizes.
If I take a subset of my data then the graph looks ok.

```
ggplot(subset(data, size == 1), aes(x = grade, y = score)) + geom_line()
```

So I wonder how can I plot my data 'score' by 'grade' for ALL combinations without the graph somehow combining all values?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: `ggplot(data, aes(x = grade, y = score, group = size)) + geom_line()` ... `group` would connected points in the line based on same `size` in this case...

Comment: @Ben thank you but suppose I wanted to just get one geom_line() for all data?

Comment: @Ben in that case do people just take the average values?

Comment: It depends on what you want to show...you could also show the "range" of values at grade 1, 2, and 3 (3 vertical lines). Or you can show the mean with or without error bars/95% confidence interval, or other...if you describe further what the data is like, or find online other graph examples that you think would tell the story of your data, we can try some different `ggplot` approaches that may meet your needs...

Comment: @Ben thanks a bunch. Can you help me show the "mean" for all values compiles with/without 95% intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach. You can plot `score` vs. `grade`, and use `stat_summary` to add a line going through mean at each `grade`, and a ribbon that contains the 95% confidence interval. Is this what you had in mind?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = grade, y = score)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun = mean, linetype = "dashed") +
  stat_summary(geom = "ribbon", fun.data= mean_cl_normal, fun.args = list(conf.int=0.95), alpha=.1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = data$grade)
```

**Plot**

[image: plot with mean and 95% CI]

Alternatively, you can plot points for mean values at each `grade` and standard error bars.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  group_by(grade) %>%
  summarise(mean_score = mean(score),
            SD = sd(score),
            n = n(),
            SE = SD/sqrt(n)) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = grade, y = mean_score)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_score - SE, ymax = mean_score + SE), width = .1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = data$grade)
```

**Plot**

[image: plot with mean points and standard errors]

Comment: this is really nice! I try it on my own data and get this error: No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se(). but I think that is ok?

Comment: what version of `ggplot2` are you using? I'm using 3.3.0

Comment: ggplot2_3.2.1 so I will update! I am now just wondering-- if lets say I wish to generate a line for all groupo
 I will update! In my example 'size' correspond to whether class size is <40 or otherwise. So we can use the method you described to get the mean across all values of size. However what if it is really unequal such that there are 500 values of size = 0 and 100 values of size = 1. Is there a way to get a weighted mean across several variables to generate a single line?

Comment: This is a bit different than what I initially understood. If you want to compute weighted means, I would do that separately outside of `ggplot` and outside of `stat_summary`. You can create a simple table of 3 means, 3 lower CI values, and 3 upper CI values, and then use `geom_line` and `geom_ribbon` to recreate a similar plot with weighted means. But it's unclear whether this is what you really are looking for. You might want to start with a new post on SO that describes more what you want to do to the data and what you might want as a final outcome for the plot?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `facet_wrap(~class+size)` this will give one plot per combination.